# If an ideal is made up by polynomials with disjoint variable parts, then those polynomials form a Grobner Basis.

Tags: abstract-algebra, symbolic-computation, groebner-basis

I've been learning symbolic computation over the summer (just independent learning) and I'm at the section of my book about Grobner bases. There's an exercise I'd like to see a proof of, but have not been able to answer. Here it is:

> Suppose that $I = (f_1,\dots,f_n)$ where
>   $$
> variables(f_i) \cap variables(f_j) = \emptyset
> $$
>   for $i\neq j$. Show that $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$ is a Grobner basis for $I$.

If anyone could help, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: What characterizations of Grobner bases are you allowed to use?

Comment: The language of the title is confusing, since it implies that you are saying an ideal is a basis.

Comment: The definition is for a $u$ in $I$, there is an $f_i$ such that the leading monomial of $f_i$ divides the leading monomial of $u$.

Or For all $u$ in $I$, $u$ reduces to 0 with respect to $F$, or for each $u$ in $I$, there is a representation $u = c_1f_1+\cdots c_nf_m$, where the leading monomial of $u$ has the same variable part as the max (with respect the lexicographic ordering) of the leading monomials of $c_if_i$.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you edit titles? Edit: Got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow [Buchberger's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger%27s_algorithm). Every step includes the next element of the generators, no elimination occurs because the variables are disjoint (step 3), and syzygies are all zero for the same reason (step 4).

Comment: I learn that algorithm in the next section =/

Is there a different way to do it?

Comment: Any proof is going to be essentially the same as this because you need to check the definition, which is going to take you to do steps $3$ and $4$ anyway. Let me disguise it.

Comment: I understand the idea though. I do have a theorem that tells me if the syzygies reduce to 0, then we have a Grobner basis. But, can I show that the syzygies reduce to 0?

Comment: I got it actually, using the syzygies was the right idea. I didn't think of it. I'll mark your answer correct. Thanks!